# Is `io.reactivex.Completable` just a substitution for `Single<Void>`?

Tags: java, rx-java2

So, from the [RxJava 2 What's new](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#nulls), it appears that one can't use nulls anymore. If one just wants to make an operations without caring about returning any result, can I just use `Completable` or is there a set of gotchas to go with that statement?

And how does it defer from the solution presented in the docs:

> This means that Observable can no longer emit any values but
>   only terminate normally or with an exception. API designers may
>   instead choose to define Observable with no guarantee on what
>   Object will be (which should be irrelevant anyway). For example, if
>   one needs a signaller-like source, a shared enum can be defined and
>   its solo instance onNext'd:

```
enum Irrelevant { INSTANCE; }

Observable<Object> source = Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<Object> emitter) -> {
   System.out.println("Side-effect 1");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);

   System.out.println("Side-effect 2");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);

   System.out.println("Side-effect 3");
   emitter.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);
});

source.subscribe(e -> { /* Ignored. */ }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: The example was provided because many use `doOnNext` to perform additional side effects which wouldn't trigger with `Completable` as there is no `onNext` there. With `Irrelevant.INSTANCE`, you don't have to change the base type from `Observable` to `Completable` in an existing code base.

Comment: Use `Completable` if you only care about a single event that tells that operation succeeded or failed. Use `Observable<Object>` if you care about multiple signal events from a source which will eventually succeed or fail.

Comment: @akarnokd, assuming a new codebase, would you recommend using Completable over Single|Observable<Void> ?

Comment: Yes, because with Void, you won't be ever able to signal any `onNext` or `onSuccess`.